# Android change orientation programmatically?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I have a single activity app. Most of the time screen must be in portrait orientation unless it shows video in full screen (I`m expecting to use ExoPlayer). So if I lock the orientation in manifest how can I rotate activity or player view itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programmatically you can change orientation by:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

or

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Just put it in a onClick event or whatever you desire.

Comment: if you are in a fragment, we may need to call getActivity() first. ex:- getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);